# In Montgomery, Alabama, how common was it to be arrested for sitting in the incorrect section of the bus?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, protests, civil-rights

Rosa Parks' arrest, which led to the [Montgomery Bus Boycott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_Bus_Boycott#Rosa_Parks), is the most famous case, while Claudette Colvin is often listed as the first. (Sometimes she is listed as first, other times as the first in 1955). Aurelia Browder, Susie McDonald, Mary Louise Smith and Jeanette Reese were also arrested in 1955.

How common was it to be arrested? The buses were segregated since 1900, are there any stats on number of arrests per year?

Comment: Btw, Parks wasn't arrested for sitting in the white section of the bus. Parks was actually in the black section of a crowded bus, and did not give up her seat to a white passenger after the white section had filled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was very rare. In Montgomery (which OP specifically asks about), the passengers  mentioned above are the only other passengers arrested before Parks, according to [History.com](http://www.history.com/news/10-things-you-may-not-know-about-rosa-parks), this [NPR story](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=101719889), and every other source I can find.

This is further corroborated by a [flyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_Bus_Boycott#Boycott) circulated by Montgomery's [Women's Political Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Political_Council) after Parks' arrest. According to the WPC (who were in a position to know) Parks was the second woman in Montgomery other than Colvin to be arrested for this:

> Another woman has been arrested and thrown in jail because she refused
>   to get up out of her seat on the bus for a white person to sit down.
>   It is the second time since the Claudette Colvin case that a Negro
>   woman has been arrested for the same thing. This has to be stopped.

However, outside of Montgomery there were protestors arrested for not giving up their seats going back to at least [Irene Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irene_Morgan) in 1944 in Virginia. [Bayard Rustin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayard_Rustin) and 15 others were arrested in the 1947 "[Journey of Reconciliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_of_Reconciliation)." [Sarah Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keys_v._Carolina_Coach_Co.) was arrested in North Carolina in 1952.

I can't find any arrests before Morgan. Many websites (for example [this one](http://www.ferris.edu/HTMLS/news/jimcrow/question/dec07/index.htm)) explicitly call her the first. There may have been scattered, unheralded incidents across the South, but Morgan was the first to be arrested in a knowing effort to protest segregation.

Answer (score 1):

There were definitely more people besides Claudette and Rosa Parks that were arrested in Alabama in regards to refusal to give up seats. There may even be more than this list and 4 of the people mentioned are from the Browder v. Gayle lawsuit mentioned in the above comment.

However:

- Bayard Rustin 1944
- Irene Morgan (1944)
- Lillie Mae Bradford (1951)
- Sarah Keys (7/31/1952)
- Claudette Colvin (3/2/1955)
- Auriella Browder (4/1955)
- Mary Louise Smith (10/21/1955)
- Susie Mcdonald (10/21/1955)

I am curious myself if there are more either before 1944 or even more between 10/21/1955 and Rosa Parks's arrest on 12/1/1955.

Comment: Links to sources would improve this answer.